# Symfony 2 return error at routing

Tags: php, symfony

When I add a new route in Symfony 2 I get the error:

> The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

Content of file `routing.yml` is:

```yaml
acme_hello:
    resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

blog_show:
    path:      /blog/{slug}
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Blog:show }
```

File `/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ));
    }

    public function indexAction2($page)
    {
        //$number = 2;
        print "dobrze";
        //return "dobrze";
        //return $response = new Response('Page not found.',   Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        //$this->render ('<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>');
    }
}
```

Comment: `Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?` Did you?

Comment: I add and too will errors, add this return "dobrze"; and eroor will such The controller must return a response.

Comment: And what's unclear?

Comment: What i must add, that watch page from string hello.

Comment: It's not pure PHP, you can't echo "something", you must use `return new Response("dobrze");`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start by reading the documentation and especially chapter "Getting Started"

http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html

Good luck ;-)